# Facebook Single Sign On to register or log-in in server (Android and Ios)

Tags: android, ios, facebook, single-sign-on, facebook-access-token

We are implementing a project where the users post and get some information from a server. The scenario is that the user can create account/login both manually (giving email and password) and with facebook credentials using SSO. I implement mostly the Android part, but my questions are general.

1. Let’s say that I have a button where SSO is called prompting the user to give his credentials. So in order to create account what should I send to the server? Get the FB email of the user and set as password the Access Token that I received? Is that Access Token unique and permanent for every FB account, meaning the each time I use the same FB credentials I get the same Access Token?
2. Is there any additional work that needs to be done on the server side? Or can the server handle the users that use their FB accounts similarly as it handles the others?

Every clarification will be really helpful. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the Facebook Android SDK? If so, manual login (with user email/password) and SSO (via the Android Facebook app) are very similar, in particular with respect to token handling.

For example if you check out the example in the SDK (at sdk\examples\simple\src\com\facebook\android) you will see that the code does something like the following (split between three files).

```
private static final String TOKEN = "access_token";
private static final String EXPIRES = "expires_in";
private static final String KEY = "facebook-session";
Facebook session = new Facebook(APP_ID);
SharedPreferences savedSession = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
session.setAccessToken(savedSession.getString(TOKEN, null));
session.setAccessExpires(savedSession.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
if (session.isSessionValid()) {
    session.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions, new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

So you have to save the session token in SharedPreferences after each successful login (that is also in the example), but the token handling and login (`authorize()`) is the same for both manual and SSO login (depending on the activityCode parameter).

Answer (score 0):

The token has a expiration timestamp, I guess the easy way is to generate the user account with the data fb will send you and store the fb token and expiration date as user attributes.